# Bottom of LCD screen flickering on certain graphics

Tags: windows, flicker, lcd

[image: LCD Flicker]

Looks like the lower portion of my LCD is trying to readjust its height.

This doesn't show up if I record the screen. It seems to only appear when displaying certain kinds of graphics... like the dark UIs of Blender and Adobe Illustrator. It also shows up if I play back a video of these troublesome GUIs in fullscreen!

What could be causing this?

**EDIT:** Fixed by moving the image up when the problem occurs.
[image: Moved image on screen to Vertical 49 instead of 50]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your monitor is adjusting the screen to fit what it is being shown. It is probably a configuration problem. You should set it to "just scan" or whichever is the equivalent on your monitor.

Comment: Oh I've tried hitting Auto-adjust, and changing every other setting in the monitor's OSD, but it doesn't affect this problem. It's not global anyway, just the bottom 10% of the screen I'd say.

Comment: The problem is exactly the opposite. Your monitor is adjusting too much, this is why it gets confused with black screens. You should hit auto adjust on a full white screen and then set it off. 
What is happening is that your monitor is self adjusting to compensate slight error in over and underscanning. This is in fact a common issue. Changing the cable from HDMI or RGB to DVI might fix it. There are also some tinkering possible with your videocard driver (try to find the overscan/underscan settings)